# Queen Mirelurk SURVIVAL

Tags: fallout-4

What is the best way to kill the Queen Mirelurk on SURVIVAL level difficulty? Missles, Rifles, and mini-nukes are practically worthless and you cannot heal in combat.  In addition the Queen's poison attack bypasses all armor (only a rare legendary item gives poison any resistance and its an insignificant amount).

Comment: You can definitely heal in combat, what makes you think you can't? I bound a bunch of healing items to my quick use buttons, it totally works in or out of combat.

Comment: @kevin: at highest difficulty, the health bar refills so slowly from first aid items its like it isn't happening.

Comment: I actually just added some more notes on fighting the queen on survival to that other answer. Mostly the same stuff as I'm seeing here. Use mines. Shoot her in the head.

Comment: If a missile launcher isn't working for you, maybe you don't have the right perks.  With all the big guns and explosives perks, it will do something like 700 damage.  Add the targeting computer mod and it will be a joke.  Fallout games (and Skyrim too for that matter) all have the same formula where you're whoafully underpowered for a time because they anticipated your upcoming perks, leveling, crafting, upgrades, etc into the equation.

Comment: I probably overdid it b/c I was expecting an immense battle, but I can tell you from experience that with maxed out melee and sneak/crit perks (ninja, etc) and popping all my buff prefix chems and a stealth boy, you can 1-shot a Mirelurk Queen on survival with a sneak crit.  I used the Rockville Slugger.  I suspect a Gauss Rifle would do it too w/ rifle perks instead of melee.

Comment: This also depends on whether you're talking about a specific Mirelurk Queen, like at The Castle, or just in general.  The one at the Castle is very easy if you use the terrain, have a lot of patience, and a good, long range-weapon.  In my latest playthrough, I killed it at level 15 with a scoped pipe rifle.. and about 200 sneak headshots.

Answer (score 6):

Mirelurk Queens are just a tougher variant of normal Mirelurks so you can kill them using the same techniques.
It is important to realize that Mirelurks have a very tough exoskeleton. Shooting the shell of a Mirelurk does not do much damage, if any.
Aim all your weapons at their soft parts (mainly their head) and take cover to avoid their spit-attacks.
There is no difference in techniques you can use between any of the difficulty settings. The higher the difficulty settings, the more bullets it takes, but that is about it.

Use mines or good aiming (or VATS) to cripple legs so it is easier to get away from them. Use cover to avoid their range attack (and regain health, slowly).
Use buffs to help reduce damage they cause or inflict more damage yourself.

One weapon I personally found very usefull is the Spray n' Pray you can buy from a roaming vendor (I can't recall her name, but seems comes across as a bit of a dope addict).
It is a submachine gun which shoots .45 bullets which explode on impact causing 15 points area of effect damage. Its destructive powers are quite impressive.

Comment: I second this, this is great

Comment: The Spray n Pray is often in sale at Bunker Hill, but I just may have been lucky.

Comment: you can get the spray n pray from Cricket, a wandering vendor - more info here: http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cricket

Comment: If there are groups of trees around, keep those between you and the queen: they can block the spit attack but you can still shoot through the gaps in the trees.

Comment: `Use mines or good aiming (or VATS) to cripple legs` [Also, kneecapper Legendary effect](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects).  Highly underrated, but very good at dealing with those tough, melee-only enemies.  I pack a kneecapper Combat Rifle everywhere I go, and it has made Deathclaws and Mirelurks and those bears basically harmless.  You can shoot the Mirelurk Queen in the shell (or anywhere else) to cripple her legs and make sure she can't catch you, then go to work on doing damage to kill her.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to find a loop there, I had an overload of mines in my inventory and I just lay down mines as a ran away. It is probably not a real method. but it worked for me. I did not have enough to kill it completely though I finished it off with this rifle "[Overseer's Guardian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l20IA.jpg)" *(not my image)*

[image]

Hope this might work for you as well.

Comment: great gun. had it, but i lost is somehow... bug or something, it's just missing. crazy angry :(

Comment: That is so horrible :(. I heard of some people losing their weapons, and if they switch to third person and back the weapons re appear, really weird, I hope that brings back your gun ;(

Comment: @DavorMlinaric If you put it in a container at a settlement, one of the settlers (or a provisioner!) might have swiped it, check their inventories.

Answer (score 2):

The Queen always comes from the same spot and approaches through the hole in the southwest wall. Here are some tips that should help with the fight:

Before deciding on a course of action with Preston, leave the Minutemen waiting where they arrive and do the following:

- clear the mirelurks and eggs from the west side of the courtyard before starting the event.
- lay down as many mines as possible - of all types - along the ground where the Queen emerges
- in order to minimize the number of mines tripped by the Minutemen, you'll want to place the bulk of them on the beach just outside the wall as well as in the crumbled wall itself.
- the Queen will make a straight line from the water where she emerges to a point just inside the broken wall. This path is what you want to mine, and mine the **** out of it.

If you place enough mines, the Queen will have a serious dent in her health before you ever start shooting her. As for the fight itself, use VATS judiciously to target her head and arms. As @Thorsal mentioned, shooting her in any shelled part is basically a waste of ammo.

Comment: Any particular reason this was downvoted? A comment would be nice.

Comment: The Mirelurk Queen at The Castle is not the only one in the game, nor does she only appear as you described.  In each of my last 3 playthroughs, I've cleared out The Castle, including killing that Mirelurk Queen before getting the quest from Preston.

Comment: Interesting. I've cleared the courtyard without her showing up. I've also used the above method successfully, although I only killed the mirelurks on that side of the courtyard before mining it. I'll take your word for it, though, and remove that part.

Comment: Her appearance (as far as I can tell) is based on the number of those Mirelurk egg clutches you clear, and you have to clear more than the ones in the courtyard.  IME, she shows up after clearing all the ones in the courtyard, all the ones inside The Castle interior, and 2 or three on top of the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the various suggestions.  Killing a queen Mirelurk on normal difficulty is a piece cake, Survival difficulty however is a completely different matter.  Even in power armor one poison hit from the Queen at level 30 will kill you.  Using .50 cal +50% damage to Mirelurk (Rheba II) with maxed rifleman perks and a perfect headshot does about 1% damage to the Queen. It will require utilizing a number of pathfinding exploits to gain/lose aggro and a lot of patience and luck to kill her this way.  The mines may be viable if dropped prior to combat starting.

Comment: I believe the Castle Queen only spawns after the 6th egg clutch is smashed, so there is time.  The downside is that if the queen deviates path even slightly, all the minutemen will be blown up.

Comment: There is a video online of a player killing the queen on survival level using every drug in the game and two extremely rare legendary melee weapons.  Interestingly enough the player in the video (high end power armor, 18 strength, 80% damage resistance) exclusively attacked the queen in the legs.  Killed her in about 5 hits. It was impressive.

Answer (score 1):

Look for a legendary weapon that deals addition 'fire/burn'  or 'bleed' damage.  Put an automatic receiver on the weapon.  I have 2 that I use for Mirelurks - an incendiary 10mm pistol that deals 15 fire damage, and a bleeder pipe rifle that deals 25 points of bleed damage.  The big advantage here is the Mirelurks high damage resistance will not effect the fire or bleed damage.